# metric conversion problem, why is my output inaccurate?

Tags: python

I am trying to understand why this code is not giving me an accurate answer to my conversion

```
import math           # for access to pi
diameterLargeZa = 35  # in Europe, a large pizza is 35cm across
cm2in = 1/2.54      # conversion ratio from centimeters to inches
radiusLargeZa = diameterLargeZa / 2            # calculate radius from diameter
radiusLargeZa = radiusLargeZa / 10             # convert to cm from mm
radiusLargeZa = radiusLargeZa * cm2in          # convert to in from cm
euro_za2 = radiusLargeZa**2 * math.pi       # calculate area from diameter
print( euro_za2 )
```

Comment: `35/2` has different results in Python2 and Python3. Which one are you using?

Comment: What is the result and what result did you expect? [edit] your question to add these details. See also [tour] and [ask].

Answer (score 1):

Why are you converting mm to cm (line 5: this is conversion from cm to decimeter)?. You already have the radius in cm.
You your code should be like this:

```
import math           # for access to pi
diameterLargeZa = 35  # in Europe, a large pizza is 35cm across
cm2in = 1/2.54      # conversion ratio from centimeters to inches
radiusLargeZa = diameterLargeZa / 2            # calculate radius from diameter
# radiusLargeZa = radiusLargeZa / 10             convert to cm from mm (this is cm to decimetre, you already have value in cm)
radiusLargeZa = radiusLargeZa * cm2in          # convert to in from cm
euro_za2 = radiusLargeZa**2 * math.pi       # calculate area from diameter
print( euro_za2 )
# 149.12777453063953
```

Comment: im trying to go from cm to inches

Comment: For that you should divide the diameter(in cm, which you already have (35)) by 2.54. For the radius, you should divide by 2

Comment: can you should me what the code would look iike?

Comment: The code is already in the answer (without radius dividing by 10). Do you know which is the expected value?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry folks, can't add a comment, not enough points. 
@Loocid **Radius is twice the diameter, not half** is it ?

Well for the answer, why would you convert it to cm if you started with cm already.

```
import math           # for access to pi
diameterLargeZa = 35  # in Europe, a large pizza is 35cm across
cm2in = 1/2.54      # conversion ratio from centimeters to inches
radiusLargeZa = diameterLargeZa / 2            # calculate radius from diameter
# Line commented, not needed.
# radiusLargeZa = radiusLargeZa / 10             # convert to cm from mm, why ?
radiusLargeZa = radiusLargeZa * cm2in          # convert to in from cm
euro_za2 = radiusLargeZa**2 * math.pi       # calculate area from diameter
print( euro_za2 )
```

Comment: im trying to go from cm to inches

Comment: cm2in is correct (line #2), i was pointing out line #5. Just remove that line and you should be fine.